# What is difference between sailing and yachting?

Tags: word-difference

I found those two terms listed in british insurance comp.

Answer (score 1):

When ships and boats use sails they are sailing.

Yachting is the use of sailing boats for sporting purposes; yacht races.

However these, and related terms have both informal meanings and technical meanings. My guess is that the insurance company will define what they mean by those terms in the small print.

Some examples of meanings that can be found:

Sailing: the occasion of a ship leaving a port. Large motor powered ferries, with no sails, do have sailings as specified in their schedules.

Yachting: any non-commercial use of a sailing vessel. [Speculation: These days there surely can't be many commercial cargo sailing ships?]

Yacht: a large luxurious motor vessel with no sails, and which is not used for racing.

Comment: Thank you Djna below citation from inc. page now more clear after your explanation.                                                                    Yachting (including yacht racing and crewing within and outside territorial waters) #                                                                     Sailing and Powerboating (within and outside territorial waters) #